# scrapy crawlspider "deny" Invalid settings

Tags: python, scrapy

`Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=rule.get("allow", None), restrict_xpaths=rule.get("restrict_xpaths", ""),deny=('guba','f10','data','fund.*?\.eastmoney\.com/\d+\.html','quote','.*so\.eastmoney.*','life','/gonggao/')),callback=rule.get("callback", ""),follow=rule.get('follow',True))`

Rule setting ↑

runing logs：

````
2019-06-27 10:33:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://guba.eastmoney.com/list,of166401.html> (referer: http://fund.eastmoney.com/LOF_jzzzl.html)
2019-06-27 10:33:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://guba.eastmoney.com/list,of164206.html> (referer: http://fund.eastmoney.com/LOF_jzzzl.html)
2019-06-27 10:33:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://guba.eastmoney.com/list,of161823.html> (referer: http://fund.eastmoney.com/LOF_jzzzl.html)```

**My settings didn't work** help
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

> deny (a regular expression (or list of)) – a single regular expression (or list of regular expressions) that the (absolute) urls must match in order to be excluded (ie. not extracted). It has precedence over the allow parameter. If not given (or empty) it won’t exclude any links.

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml

This means that `deny` is a list of regular expressions that should **match** url. The patterns defined in your code do not match the urls you are crawling - you need to add wildcards at the beginning and the end if you want *contains* sort of matching:

```
 $ ptpython                                                                                                            
>>> import re                                                                                                         
>>> url = "http://guba.eastmoney.com/list,of161823.html"                                                              
>>> re.match('guba', url)                                                                                             
>>> re.match('.+guba.+', url)                                                                                         
<re.Match object; span=(0, 44), match='http://guba.eastmoney.com/list,of161823.html'>
```